# Error 403: AuthorizationFailed in SSO service Configuration

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

after login page its go to consent page and ask for allowing user information. once clicking allow it's throwing the error "Error 403: AuthorizationFailed". Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: entering the correct password might help ;)

Comment: i entered the correct the password only and the login also got successful, but it showing the same error

Comment: i'll share you the link, please check and confirm. [link]http://jill.mybluemix.net

Comment: Please provide more information: are you using Cloud Directory? LDAP? Other? It could be useful if you share some code with us

Comment: i'm using both cloud directory and google apis. Both were getting the same error. while pressing the allow button in the Consent page.

Comment: VCAP_Services for SSO        "name": "jill-sso",
         "label": "SingleSignOn",
"plan": "standard","credentials": {
            "secret": "jhumVGlLxQ",
            "tokenEndpointUrl": "https://jill-sso-94y7rp6se1-cl12.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/token",
            "authorizationEndpointUrl": "https://jill-sso-94y7rp6se1-cl12.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/oidc/endpoint/default/authorize",
            "issuerIdentifier": "jill-sso-94y7rp6se1-cl12.iam.ibmcloud.com",
            "clientId": "XfNTI0ecqR",
            "serverSupportedScope": [
               "openid"
            ]

Comment: It's always worth to check the bluemix health page for known errors or downtime first. Especially with SSO I had a number of weird behaviors due to known service defects.

Answer (score 0):

When I opened your link http://jill.mybluemix.net, I am getting "404 Not Found: Requested route ('jill.mybluemix.net') does not exist." Did you remove your app? If you still have the problem, you can open a Bluemix ticket at https://support.eu-gb.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/.